# CR is not working in ZSH

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

In most of the time, my zsh works correctly:

[image: Most of the time, it works fine.]

However, sometimes its behaviours became weird, and I would like to know how to deal with this problem. (So far, I have to open a new terminal tab to have the correct output).

[image: Sometimes, the carriage return is not working.]

My .zshrc is [here](https://gist.github.com/heronyang/9d080b21955ccdcbd59f), which was modified from https://github.com/jez/dotfiles

Comment: What does `zsh --version` print? (Also, why is this question tagged [bash]?)

Comment: I got `zsh 5.0.5 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stty sane` might bring back your terminal to a correct behavior.